# How to get select value on form in php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to get a selected value on the form.

Suppose If I select category "car" from sub-category "nissan".
I want this value on php.

Not value 1 and 1 because I do not recognise what value is selected.
I want name or unique value in my php file.

This is php file on the same page:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['select1'])){
    $select1 = $_POST['select1'];
}

if(isset($_POST['select2'])){
 $select2 = $_POST['select2'];
}

?>


 <html>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js 
 </script>
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) ?>" method="post">
<select name="select1" id="select1">
 <option value=""></option>
 <option value="1">car</option>
 <option value="2">phone</option>
 <option value="3">tv</option>
</select>


<select name="select2" id="select2">
 <option value=""></option>
 <option value="1">toyota</option>
 <option value="1">nissan</option>
 <option value="1">bmw</option>
 <option value="2">Iphone</option>
 <option value="2">LG</option>
 <option value="2">Samsung</option>
 <option value="3">Philips</option>
 <option value="3">Samsung</option>
</select>
</form>
</html>

<script>
 $("#select1").change(function() {
  if ($(this).data('options') == undefined) {
  /*Taking an array of all options-2 and kind of embedding it on the select1*/
  $(this).data('options', $('#select2 option').clone());
  }
  var id = $(this).val();
  var options = $(this).data('options').filter('[value=' + id + ']');
  $('#select2').html(options);
 });
</script>
```

Any idea or suggestions would be welcome
Thank You.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you want "car" instead of `1`, you will need to change the Value of the Option. If you do not want to do that or can't, then use the value as an Index to an array or pull the proper data from your data source.

Comment: @Twisty Thanks for the reply. If I change the value of the option instead of car, then when I select the car the sub-value related to car wont show. Like "Toyota" "Nissan" "BMW".

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the `value` property from all your options if you want to receive the text on the server instead. Try this

```js
// get all categories and sub categories
let categories = {};
$('#select2 option[data-category]').each(function(i, element){
    let category = $(this).data('category');

    // add category
    if( categories[category] == undefined ) categories[category] = [];
    // add sub category to category
    categories[category].push(element.textContent);
    // remove the option from the DOM
    element.remove();
});

// append related sub categories to #select 2
$("#select1").change(function() {
    let subs = categories[this.value] ?? []; // sub categories for selected category
    $('#select2').html('<option></option>').append(subs.map(txt => `<option>${txt}</option>`));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) ?>" method="post">
    <select name="select1" id="select1">
        <option></option>
        <option>car</option>
        <option>phone</option>
        <option>tv</option>
    </select>
    <select name="select2" id="select2">
        <option></option>
        <option data-category="car">toyota</option>
        <option data-category="car">nissan</option>
        <option data-category="car">bmw</option>
        <option data-category="phone">Iphone</option>
        <option data-category="phone">LG</option>
        <option data-category="phone">Samsung</option>
        <option data-category="tv">Philips</option>
        <option data-category="tv">Samsung</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

hmm, Add the data attribute in the parent option and give a value like data-parent='1'
and change value='car'

same you can do with child data-child='1' and value="toyota"

then simply target the data attribute in js and remove other options from the child options